Phase Response and Phase Delay
I am just confused regarding the negative sign in the expression for phase delay. That is, why is the phase delay negative of the phase response divided by the angular frequency; why not just the phase response divided by the angular frequency.

That's simply a consequence of the sign choice of the Fourier Transform. The forward transform uses $e^{-j\omega t}$ and the inverse $e^{+j\omega t}$. That choice makes the phase of a pure time delay negative, i.e.
$$\delta (t-\tau) \leftrightarrow e^{-j\omega \tau} $$
So for convenience we define the phase delay and group delay using the negative phase so they will be (mostly) positive for positive time delays and negative for negative time delays.

Thank you very much.

I don't think that's the reason, Hilmer.  When you have a positive delay, that must be associated with a negative phase. $$ \cos(\omega t + \phi) = \cos\big(\omega(t-\tau_\phi)\big) $$  If the phase delay $\tau_\phi>0$ (which means delay, not an acausal advance in time), then $\phi=-\omega\tau_\phi$ must be negative.  At least before phase wrapping happens.
